# How to change page orientation to landscape

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am developing windows phone app. I created one user control page for popup window.

But my application is in landscape mode then How to change user control page orientation to landscape mode?

Answer (score 0):

You should set the SupportedOrientations property of all pages to Landscape:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyWindowsPhone.Page"
   ... other attributes omitted
   SupportedOrientations="Landscape">
<!-- controls go here -->
</UserControl>
```